# curl_getinfo() keep returning 1

Tags: php, curl

I am doing a curl request and for some reason it just returns 1. The curl request is successful because i do see the response i am looking for. However it just returns 1. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated

```
$ch = curl_init($end_point);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_body);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        var_dump($http_status,"Code");
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out the answer. I forgot to add

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```